# how to convert firebase time stamp to date angular

Tags: angular

typescipt

```
    public Patients: Observable<any>;
    constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) {
        this.Patients = this.db.collection('Patients').valueChanges();
```

// get data from firebase :

```
     ngOnInit(): void {
    this.Patients.subscribe((response) => {
      this.prepareData(response);
      this.console.log(response);
    });
  }
```

// in this section use for add data to apexcharts

```
      prepareData(patients) {
    
     patients.forEach((patient) => {
    
      });
      }
```

Comment: How does a "firebase timestamp" look like? Can you include such a string in the question?

Comment: firebase time stamp // Object { seconds: 1612890000, nanoseconds: 0 }  i want to change 
 to this 2019-07-07

Answer (score 0):

I guess the firebase Timestamp is in ISO 8601 and thats not fully supported by the JavaScript Date method.

To convert it for further use you could try something like:

```js
const firebaseDate = "20190412T131518.000Z";
const convertedDate = new Date(firebaseDate.replace(/(....)(..)(.....)(..)(.*)/, '$1-$2-$3:$4:$5'));
console.log(convertedDate);
```

**EDIT**
just saw your comment reply you can simply pass the seconds to the date method

```js
const firebaseObj = { seconds: 1612890000, nanoseconds: 0 }
const convertedDate = new Date(firebaseObj.seconds)

console.log(convertedDate)
```

Comment: in this section   prepareData(patients) {
    
     patients.forEach((patient) => {
    
      });
      }

Comment: yes I assume the patient has the timestamp as the object you mentiond so you would be able to access it by patient.timestamp.seconds. Then you could do something like patient.date = new Date(patient.timestamp.seconds)

Answer (score 0):

The firebase timestamp offers a `toDate` method that basically returns a Date object.

You can create some utility types and guards that might come in handy when dealing with Firestore records.

```js
export interface FireTimeStamp extends Date {
    toDate: () => Date;
}

export type TimeStamp = Date | FireTimeStamp;

export const isFireStamp = (value: FireTimeStamp | Date | unknown): value is FireTimeStamp =>
    (value as FireTimeStamp)?.toDate && (value as FireTimeStamp)?.toDate() !== undefined;

export const isTimeStamp = (value: TimeStamp | unknown): value is TimeStamp =>
    isFireStamp(value) || value instanceof Date;
```

And here is a utility function for getting the date when you're not sure if it's a Date object or firebase time stamp object.

```js
export const toDate = (date: TimeStamp): Date => isFireStamp(date) ? date.toDate() : date;
```

You can also have a custom pipe to convert the date if you need to display it.

```js
@Pipe({
    name: 'toDate'
})
export class ToDatePipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(date: TimeStamp): Date {
        return toDate(date);
    }
}
```